# JSON in AS3. Can't find the bug

Tags: json, actionscript-3

My code:

```
 var el = event.location;
    var m  = el.substr(el.indexOf('?Mess:')+6).replace(/%20/g,' ').replace(/%22/g,'"') ;
    trace('*** Going to parse: '+m);
    trace(JSON.parse( m));
```

I can't find the reason why it gives me the following error:

> Going to validate:     game={"gadat":"2017-06-21T07:09:46.535Z","w":2,"h":3,"score":0,"games":0,"sops":"1","picform":"jpg","maxf":16,"turn":0}
>
> SyntaxError: Error #1132: Invalid JSON parse input.
>           at JSON$/parseCore()
>           at JSON$/parse()
>           at AIR_fla::MainTimeline/onChange()[AIR_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:103]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `'game='` from your JSON string.

One obvious way to do it is to just set `m` as the substring without `'game='`.

```
 var el = event.location;
    var m  = el.substr(el.indexOf('?Mess:')+6).replace(/%20/g,' ').replace(/%22/g,'"') ;
    m = m.substring(5);
    trace('*** Going to parse: '+m);
    trace(JSON.parse( m));
```

But I'd recommend finding a cleaner way to parse your location object so that it only returns the JSON object itself without the `'game='` parameter.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I am using StageWebView. It truly sucks. Although, I have found the way of passing the data from Flash to JS by generating JS file, passing the data back seem possible only thru window.location